# detect browser language and redirect to another URL

Tags: wordpress, redirect, browser, detect

I have WordPress installed on "hostingX.com"
I need to redirect to another page when browser is in English.
For example, my WordPress is in Spanish and you can access via this URL "hostingX.com/".
I've created a page called /hello-english/.
You can access to "hostingX.com/hello-english/"
I want redirect user to this page only when the browser language is English.
Can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_lang_found' );
function custom_lang_found(){
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    if ($lang == "en" ){
        if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/" ) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],get_home_url()) === false)) {
            $url = get_home_url()."/en/";
            if ( wp_redirect( $url ) ) {
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where I must enter this code, within functions? 
this will not make redirections on any page of my wordpress allways? I only need redirect "home page"  to "/hello-english/"

Comment: Thanks! I understand the code, but I don't now how can I execute it? I have written inside theme functions (line 1), but it doesn't work. Where should I write that?

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you please add above code in your `functions.php` ?

Comment: Thanks! I have written this function on functions and works. But, is_home or is_front_end returns empty and never enter. 
On the other hand, if there is a direct link to "hosting.com" (to see the page in Spanish), will always lead /hello-english/ ? You will never access to see the default WordPress page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xill-language plugin. This plugin check the browser language and change to other language. I can use plugin in wordpress. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/xili-language/

Comment: this plugins seems to be to translate the site into another language, I just need to redirect to a url

Comment: Yes. As my thinking. This plugin is not auto translate. It is manual. I did Japanese website. This website contain Japanese Language & English Language. When the client www.example.com with Japanese browser, website is redirect to www.example.com/jp. When the client www.example.com with English browser, website is redirect to www.example.com/en.

You can see browser detect language in screen shot. 
https://ps.w.org/xili-language/assets/screenshot-4.png?rev=970404

Comment: Thanks Su, but I don't find the place where write(select) the page to redirect to english lang. How can I select it?

Comment: Yes Rocio. You need to create at least 2 language. Example - English & Spanish. And then set the default language. If Spanish is default language, the client can see redirect to English language when the client browser is English. You install and you can do as the screenshot link https://wordpress.org/plugins/xili-language/screenshots/.